# How to convert list of given order to json of given order

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of this order

```
 text = ['code1','matrix result from one','code2','matrix result from two']
```

I want output in json as :

```
 text = {"code1" : "matrix result from one", "code2" : "matrix result from two"}
```

How can i do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: `{k: v for k, v in zip(*[iter(text)]*2)}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.dumps()` to convert data to a string of a JSON object and `json.loads()` to create a JSON object.

```
import json
text = ['code1','matrix result from one','code2','matrix result from two']
json_dump = json.dumps(text)
print(json_dump)
```